# Update md-progress-linear without triggering $digest

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear) of `md-progress-linear` declares the following;

```
<md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}">
</md-progress-linear>
```

And then updates it like this;

```
$interval(function() {
      self.determinateValue += 1;    
      if (self.determinateValue > 100) self.determinateValue = 30;
    }, 100);
```

This however will trigger a `$digest` every 100 milliseconds, causing all watches and bindings etc to additionally be updated every 100 milliseconds.

Is there a way to display a smoothly animated, determinate `md-progress-linear` without needing to trigger a `$digest` on each tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly true :

$interval triggers an *$apply* call, not a *$digest*. The difference is (basically) that an $apply call will cause all watches from the **whole** scope tree to be checked (from $rootScope), where a $digest only target a **given** scope (and it's children)

If you know that the method called by interval will only impact a given scope tree ( aka : the scope and it's children tree ) and not the whole rootScope tree, you can, to improve performances, do this instead :

```
$interval(function() {
      self.determinateValue += 1;    
      if (self.determinateValue > 100) self.determinateValue = 30;
      $scope.$digest();
    }, 100, 0, false);
```

the 'false' 4th param is "invokeApply=false", asking NOT to call $rootScope.apply after the method execution. Instead, you are manually calling $digest on you scope at the end of the method (you could even trigger the digest only if your condition is true, avoiding the digest cycle when your handler does nothing).

(the third param is the repeat count, and is needed to add the 4rth parameter.. 0 -> infinite repeat, as if called with only 2 params)

Note that, as said, the code sample will work, given that the md-progress-linear directive's scope is the *$scope* or one of it children.

This is the best you can do, as there is no way to ask md-process-linear to updates without a $digest cycle.

(With a custom directive, you could have worked your way with events instead of watch, but for this need, this seems overcomplicated, calling targeted $digest instead of $apply is, most of the time, really enough, performance-wise)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation.  I've added an answer to include the code solution I was able to implement based off this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using $interval, you could use $timeout and change the CSS transition

```js
self.determinateValue = 0
$timeout(function() {
  self.determinateValue = 70        
}, 100)
```

```css
md-progress-linear .md-container .md-bar2 {
    transition: transform 1.5s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based off [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022619/469777).

**Before**

All `PageController` `$watch`es are examined/updated.

```
<div ng-controller="PageController as vm">
    ...
    <md-progress-linear 
        md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}">
    </md-progress-linear>
    ...
</div>
```

```
function PageController($interval) {
    ...
    $interval(function() {
          self.determinateValue += 1;    
          if (self.determinateValue > 100) self.determinateValue = 30;
    }, 100);
    ...
}
```

**After**

Only the `ProgressController` `$watch` is examined/updated.

```
<div ng-controller="PageController as vm">
    ...
    <md-progress-linear 
        ng-controller="ProgressController as vm" 
        md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}">
    </md-progress-linear>
    ...
</div>
```

```
function PageController($interval, $scope) {
    ...
    $interval(function() {
          self.determinateValue += 1;    
          if (self.determinateValue > 100) self.determinateValue = 30;
          $scope.$broadcast("progress-update");
    }, 100, 0, false);
    ...
}

function ProgressController($scope) {
    $scope.$on("progress-update", function () { $scope.$digest(); });
}
```